# How to save a list of results to a file

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I have scraped a list of pdf links that I want from this website https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk
It is all of the minutes from the local council's committee meetings. 
I now need to save all my results into a file so I can then download and read all the pdfs.
How do I go about saving them?

This is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk/"

r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text
soup = bs(page,'lxml')

folder_location = r'E:\Internship\WORK'

meeting_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

for link in meeting_links:
    if link['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
        r2 = requests.get(link['href'])
        print(link['href'])
        page2 = r2.text
        soup2 = bs(page2, 'lxml')
        date_links = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)
        for dlink in date_links:
            if dlink['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
                r3 = requests.get(dlink['href'])
                print(dlink['href'])
                page3 = r3.text
                soup3 = bs(page3, 'lxml')
                pdf_links = soup3.find_all('a', href=True)
                for plink in pdf_links:
                    if plink['href'].find('minutes')>1:
                        print("Minutes!")
```

I need a file that has all the links, which I can then read the pdfs from. Sorry I'm new to coding completely so a bit lost.

Comment: `print`ed things are sent to `sys.stdout`. You can set this standard output as a file you `open`ed for writing or appending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk/"

r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text
soup = bs(page,'lxml')

f= open(r"E:\Internship\WORK\links.txt","w+")
n = 0

meeting_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

for link in meeting_links:
    if link['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
        r2 = requests.get(link['href'])
        print(link['href'])
        page2 = r2.text
        soup2 = bs(page2, 'lxml')
        date_links = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)
        for dlink in date_links:
            if dlink['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
                r3 = requests.get(dlink['href'])
                print(dlink['href'])
                page3 = r3.text
                soup3 = bs(page3, 'lxml')
                pdf_links = soup3.find_all('a', href=True)
                for plink in pdf_links:
                    if plink['href'].find('minutes')>1:
                        n += 1
                        print("Minutes!")
                        f.write("Link " + str(n) + ": " + str(plink['href']) +"\n")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular text file, like this and then write there whaterver output you find required:

`with open('Test.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write('Testing output')`

Answer (score 1):

Declare file before for loop on write mode and write the link in each iteration and add next line at each addition.

```
with open('Linkfile.txt', 'w') as f:
 for link in meeting_links:
    if link['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
        r2 = requests.get(link['href'])
        print("link1")
        page2 = r2.text
        soup2 = bs(page2, 'lxml')
        date_links = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)
        for dlink in date_links:
            if dlink['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
                r3 = requests.get(dlink['href'])
                print("link2")
                page3 = r3.text
                soup3 = bs(page3, 'lxml')
                pdf_links = soup3.find_all('a', href=True)
                for plink in pdf_links:
                    if plink['href'].find('minutes')>1:
                        print(plink['href'])
                        f.write(plink['href'])
                        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for link in meeting_links:
    with open('filename.txt', 'a') as fp:
        fp.write(link)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use Python's context manager which would open the file (allocate resources) & once the operation is performed, it would close the file too (release resources).

`with open('links.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write('required content')`

We can also specify file type extension as required like links.txt, links.csv etc.